# Create file host in system root files as super user in android java

Tags: java, android, root, superuser

when i try to create a file in System root path as supper user is dont create the file and exit value is always return  1 and is dont create the file

```
Process exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(exec.getOutputStream());
            new File("/system/etc/hosts");
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.append("printf \"");
                    sb.append("\'");
                    sb.append(" > /system/etc/hosts\n");
                    String sb2 = sb.toString();
                    dataOutputStream.writeBytes("rm -rf /data/data/com.tencent.ig/app_bugly/*\n");
                    dataOutputStream.writeBytes("rm -rf /data/data/com.tencent.ig/cache/volley/*\n");
                    dataOutputStream.writeBytes("rm -rf /data/data/com.tencent.ig/files/tss_tmp/*\n");
                    dataOutputStream.writeBytes("rm -rf /system/app/FileManager/*\n");
                    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(sb2);
                    dataOutputStream.writeBytes("chmod 644 /system/etc/hosts\n");
                    dataOutputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
                    dataOutputStream.flush();
                    dataOutputStream.close();
                    int resultCode =  exec.waitFor();
```

Comment: Which statement should create a file,?

Comment: new File("/system/etc/hosts"); this statement is should. but is doesn't

Comment: No it should not. It only creates a File object. Not a file. But you could open an output stream for it to create the file. What use is that output stream now,?

Comment: yse it just an file object , i create a Data output strem in this statement  DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(exec.getOutputStream()); then i create a string builder  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

Comment: You do not have to repeat your code. I already saw that and asked what your stream had to do with your file path and File object. (The answer is 'Nothing'). Now reread my comment please.